# Error when trying to split the data in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 

files = glob.glob("filepath/*.csv",)
df = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in files]

data = pd.concat(df,ignore_index=True)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 2)

Answer (score 0):

As per [scikit-doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)
The number of return list will be `2 * len(arrays)`. Since you are only giving it a single "array" which is `data`, `train_test_split` will split your dataframe in 2, `X_train, X_test`.

```
X_train, X_test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

If your dataframe contains the X and Y data, you can do

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(data['X'], data['Y'], test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```